# Where is Ubuntu storing installed programs?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-11.04

I am using Ubuntu and when I click on a program to download Firefox asks me "What should firefox do with this file?"
And in the "Open with" I would like to find a program "Package installer".
The problem is - I don't know where to look for. Where is the program stored (I installed it using Ubuntu Software Center)

Comment: Not programming related - should go to superuser.com.

Comment: Actually, it should go to askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you installed the package with the Ubuntu package manager (apt, synaptic, dpkg or similar), you can get information about the installed package with

```
dpkg -L <package_name>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a search if I don't know exact name of the program. i'm asking because the name of the program is "Package installer", therefore I tried with "package_installer", "package-installer", "package", and I can't find it

Comment: `dpkg -l` lists all installed packages.  You can use something like `dpkg -l | grep package` and than use `dpkg -L <name>`.  Nevertheless it is strange to add packages the way you are doing it.  Typically this is done with the help of tools which are mostly always installed when using Ubuntu like `apt-get` or `synaptic`.

Comment: @Dantes If you write `dpkg -L p` and press tab, it will show you the name of packages that starts with p installed on your system.

Answer (score 64):

They are usually stored in the following folders:

```
/bin/
/usr/bin/
/sbin/
/usr/sbin/
```

If you're not sure, use the `which` command:

```
~$ which firefox
/usr/bin/firefox
```

Comment: Thanks @Paul Oliver. Simple answer but great help

Comment: @itsols no it's not.  Try which sublime-text ... you get NOTHING

Comment: @boctulus You should try **which subl** it give you the folder.

Comment: itsols but how can I know I should look for "subl" in first place? It's nonsense.

Answer (score 19):

Simply, type the command:

`~$ whereis "program name"`

Comment: What is program name? The name that appears in the launcher?

Answer (score 4):

for some applications, for example google chrome, they store it under /opt. 
you can follow the above instruction using dpkg -l to get the correct naming
then dpkg -L  to get the detail.

hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Just for an addition reference to the above answers. I can not use `dpkg -L` to find the correct path for cuda.
See the results I got from `dpkg -L`

```
$ dpkg -L cuda
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/cuda
/usr/share/doc/cuda/copyright
/usr/share/doc/cuda/changelog.Debian.gz
```

the correct path is `/usr/local/cuda`

```
$ ll /usr/local | grep cuda

lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    8 Oct 20 18:45 cuda -> cuda-9.0/

drwxr-xr-x 15 root root 4096 Oct 20 18:44 cuda-9.0/
```

Btw, I did install cuda by the command of

```
dpkg -i xx_cuda_xxx.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

to find the program you want you can run this command at terminal:

```
find / usr-name "your_program"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the folder such as **brushes**, **curves**, etc. you can try:

`/home/<username>/.gimp-2.8`

This folder will contain all the `gimp folders`.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `google-chrome` it might be inside your chrome extension, you can just remove the extension and use the downloaded & updated version (ubuntu 20.04)